# ag-grid api.refreshView() does not seem to be working

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

The data that I load in ag grid depends on an http call and once I get the data I call the api.setRowData(data); and during debugging I see that the data that I need is there. But the grid does not show the entire data at first http response. When I make a second call only then it shows the data. Here is what I do once I get the data from http call:

```
gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);
gridOptions.api.refreshView();
```

Also in the gridOptions, I mention:

```
onGridReady: function() {
                    gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
                    gridOptions.api.refreshView();
                }
```

Any idea what is the issue?

Comment: Can you try to call `gridOptions.api.refreshInMemoryRowModel()`?

Answer (score 0):

This single line worked for me.

```
onGridReady: function(event) {
    event.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
}
```

You may need to instantiate your grid inside an EventListener also.

Answer (score -1):

I have replaced `refreshView` with `refreshInMemoryModel()`. It worked for me.